# Migrating from SqlMembershipProvider to Custom Provider 

Tags: asp.net, encryption, hash, membership, sqlmembershipprovider

Here's the scenario:
I have used default SqlMembershipProvider to implement membershp on a website. Now I'd like to migrate to my custom membership provider. (FYI the provide I use is [CodeFirst Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/).
The problem is, the provider uses a custom encryption/hash algorithm to store passwords in db and I don't want to generate new passwords for every user and mail them the new password.

How can I implement default membership password hashing/encryption in my provider. I used reflector/googled and tried the following code which seems to be the default implementation in SqlMembershipProvider:

```
internal static string GenerateSalt()
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[16];
    (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
}

internal string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
    byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
    byte[] bRet = null;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
   HashAlgorithm s = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
   bRet = s.ComputeHash(bAll);
   return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
}
```

And used it in my `ValidateUser` method:

```
  string salt = GenerateSalt();
  string pass = EncodePassword(enteredPassword, salt);
  bool verificationSucceeded = pass == user.Password;
```

But the pass returned from `EncodePassword` is different from the one that the default `SqlMembershipProvider` has put into database before switching to custom membership. How can I implement the exact password validation/generation like Default `SqlMembershipProvider`?

Note: since I have not defined any `machinekey` in my web.config, I'm sure the default provider used `Hashed` Password Format, not `Encrypted` or `Clear`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

in `ValidateUser` method, we have to get `PasswordSalt` from `aspnet_Membership` table, not generating it!

Dummy question. :|

Comment: A dumb question is one not asked.  If you didn't know, there were many others who didn't either, who this question helped.

Comment: As Andrew said, I've just come across this today and it was exactly what I have needed.  Thank you.